# How to unit test a callback function was called on a React component using Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, cypress

I am trying to use [cypress-react-unit-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test) to unit test my React components.

In this instance I have a Button, that gets passed a callback function to execute on click. I have the code below but fails immediately at the line highlighted. The error message is `expected stub to have been called at least once, but it was never called`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'cypress-react-unit-test';

const Button = ({ onClick }) => (
  <button onClick={onClick} data-test-ref="button">
    Hello
  </button>
);

describe('Button', () => {
  it('should call the onClick function', () => {
    const onClick = cy.stub();

    mount(<Button onClick={onClick} />);
    cy.get(`[data-test-ref=button]`).click();

    // expect(onClick).to.be.called; // fails
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I test that the onClick prop was executed when the button is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: hi there, are you sure the `click` function is working or not from the UI? if yes, then you can make use of the `cypress-react-selector` to validate the new value of a certain prop. You can this example list [here](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test/blob/main/cypress/component/advanced/react-book-example/src/components/ProductsList.spec.js)

Comment: Hello. With the `expect` statement uncommented the test fails straight away without the UI even rendering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially, the `expect()` is getting executed before the Cypress commands get a chance to run.

You need to chain the expect inside a `.then()` as per the [toggle-spec](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test/blob/main/cypress/component/basic/toggle-example/toggle-spec.js) example,

```
describe('Button', () => {
  it('should call the onClick function', () => {
    const onClick = cy.stub();

    mount(<Button onClick={onClick} />);
    cy.get(`[data-test-ref=button]`).click()
    .then(() => {
      expect(onClick).to.be.called; // succeeds
    });

  });
});
```

Or alias the stub as per the [stub](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test/tree/main/cypress/component/basic/stub-example) example,

```
describe('Button', () => {
  it('should call the onClick function', () => {
    const onClick = cy.stub().as('my-button');

    mount(<Button onClick={onClick} />);
    cy.get(`[data-test-ref=button]`).click();

    cy.get('@my-button').should('have.been.called'); 
  });
});
```

Comment: The documentation shows examples with "click" then "assert".... NONE of them mention a promise. Thanks for this SO answer... I really wish the documentation mentioned that the events were asynchronous.